# Delete accounts with Razor Web Pages

Tags: razor, membership, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

So, I'm working through a basic membership management admin panel but I can't quite figure out how to delete a user account. I can create one easily enough with the WebSecurity class, but this class doesn't appear to have any functions to delete an account.

What exactly do i have to do to get this functionality?

**Edit:** If you are using ASP.NET Web Pages 2 you are now able to accomplish the above by calling the ***DeleteUser()*** and ***DeleteAccount()*** functions available in WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.  If you are using ASP.NET Web Pages 1 the answer is still valid.  Refer to the [SimpleMembershipProvider Class MSDN documenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write your own code to delete the account. It's simply an entry in your database, so use the Database helper to remove the relevant rows from the webpages_UserInRoles,webpages_Membership and UserProfile tables.

Answer (score 0):

The checkmarked answer is incorrect. Use

```
Membership.DeleteUser()
```

Comment: As stated in the body of the message, I was using the WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity class available to ASP.NET Web Pages out of the box. Granted, Web Page's WebSecurity class interacts with System.Web.Security.Membership, but uses a different MembershipProvider (SimpleMembershipProvider instead of SqlMembershipProvider ). If I was using the ASP.NET Membership in, say, a WebForms app, then the Membership.DeleteUser() function applies. WebForms and Web Pages use different database schemas under the covers largely because they are using different MembershipProviders.

Comment: No. This works with simplemembershipprovider as you've stated you are using the WebSecurity class available to Web Pages and web pages uses simplemembership. I've used this myself.

Comment: I apologize, I haven't used ASP.NET Web Pages 2 and it appears that SimpleMembershipProvider was extended to add DeleteUser() function (and many others). I was using Web Pages 1 when I asked the question over a year ago. I'll update my answer to include this information. Thanks!